# Using AssetsLoader in Pixi.js with typescript

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

It seems that in latest definitions of pixi (like https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/typescript/pixi.d.ts) there is no more property onComplete in AssetLoader. So how should I use AssetLoader now? Please, provide examples, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a listener on your AssetLoader for the "onComplete" event.
Something like this (assuming your Assetloader is instantiated into this._assetsLoader):

```
var allAssetsLoadedCallback = () => this.allAssetsLoaded();
this._assetsLoader.addEventListener("onComplete", allAssetsLoadedCallback);
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried like you said, but it still wouldn't work. But after going through pixi's code I managed to find out that there is problem with my JSON, so I now investigate this one.